# insertar un icono en un elemento td usando jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola amigos resulta que estoy tratando de hacer un código para que cuando inserte un registro con ajax junto al registro aparezcan los íconos de editar.
Tengo esta parte pero en el td me aparece es un OBJECT:

```
var enlaceEditar=$('<a>',{
                      'href':'Vista/registros-controlador.php'
                    }).append($('<i>'),{
                       'class':'fas fa-edit'
                    });






                    var nuevo_registro='<tr>'+'<th class="text-center">'+parseInt(fecha.getFullYear())+'-'+parseInt((fecha.getMonth()+1))+'-'+parseInt(fecha.getDate())+'</th>'+
                    '<td class="text-center">'+resultado.horas+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center">'+resultado.publicaciones+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center">'+resultado.videos+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center">'+resultado.revisitas+'</td>'+
                    '<td class="text-center">'+enlaceEditar+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>'; 

                    fila.append(nuevo_registro);
```

[image: Lo que me sale]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el problema es que en tu variable `enlaceEditar` esatas obteniendo un obejto jQuery.

cambia tu enlaceEditar por lo siguiente :

```
var enlaceEditar = '<a href="Vista/registros-controlador.php" ><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>'
```

Comment: Manuel gracias así como dices me funcionó

Comment: Por nada Jesu!. pero la mejor manera de agradecer es aceptando la respuesta como "la mejor" o marcándola como útil. Así otras personas con los mismos inconvenientes verán directamente la solución al problema!.